# Can anyone suggest a flow that helps in processing large JSON data from Split to Merge content processor

Tags: json, split, apache-nifi

[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDKQL.png)
As you see in the flow the flow files are moving in bits and pieces from the split json queue to merge content and from merge content to convertrecord.

I have increased the threshold to 30000 and I need to process data beyond that threshold.

Also I need to get all the data into a single CSV file.

I am new to Apache Nifi and any suggestions are highly appreciated..

Comment: what's the reason to split and then merge flow files?

Comment: Actually I am collecting JSON data (large amount of data) from servers so I'm splitting the data Flattening it  and merging it and then converting into CSV file. My actual problem is when I'm merging the data due to threshold (max I could give is 30000) only partial data is converting into CSV ,so i'm not getting data as required. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Convertrecord allows you to convert record format. So, you don't need to split/merge. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertRecord/index.html